# С помощью split разделить число по нечётным цифрам

Tags: javascript

```js
function hi(x) {
  const y = x.split(":");

  for (var i = 0; i < y.length; ++i) {
    if (i % 2 == 1 && i + 1 % 2 == 1) {
      i.push(y);

    }
    return y
  }

}

console.log(hi(55639217));
```

Я хочу разделить число по нечётным цифрам. Если человек вводит `55639217`, функция должна вернуть `5:563:921:7`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function hi(x) {
  var result = [];

  var y = (x + "").split("");
  for (var i = 0; i < y.length; ++i) {
    result.push(y[i]);
    if (y[i] % 2 == 1 && y[i + 1] % 2 == 1) {
      result.push(":");
    }
  }
    
  return result.join("");;  
}

console.log(hi(55639217));
console.log(hi(556392172));
```

Comment: @AniPetrosyan отметьте ответ как принятый, если он вам помог)